# In cordova is there any way to implement push notification with slider in it to control suppose a textbox value?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, slider

I am using phonegap plugin to send action button push notification.

**Use Case:** Suppose User receives a push notification asking him how much quantity he wants.
Currently he can put value inside a Textbox and press enter, as shown in the image link.
[Action Button Push notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwEoC.jpg)

Desired Case: Instead of entering a number inside this Textbox, is it possible user can change this value via slider. It increases usability.

Is it possible to do that in Cordova?